# How to download files that I found using grep in MacOS

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to download logs via ssh (from remote location - linux server) from  multiples folder that I found with grep:

Folders hierarchy:

```
thread1
  main
    main-22-11-2019.log
      Text in file: apple is green
    main-21-11-2019.log
      Text in file: wood is green
    main-20-11-2019.log
      Text in file: code is green
  functions
    functions-22-11-2019.log
      Text in file: apple is green
    functions-21-11-2019.log
      Text in file: wood is green
    functions-20-11-2019.log
      Text in file: apple is green
thread2
   main
     main-22-11-2019.log
       Text in file: apple is green
     main-21-11-2019.log
       Text in file: code is green
     main-20-11-2019.log
       Text in file: wood is green
   functions
     functions-22-11-2019.log
       Text in file: wood is green
     functions-21-11-2019.log
       Text in file: code is green
     functions-20-11-2019.log 
       Text in file: apple is green
.
.
.
```

I am searching content in files with grep:

```
grep -rl "apple" ./thread1/main/*.log ./thread1/functions/*.log ./thread2/main/*.log ./thread2/functions/*.log ./thread3/main/*.log ./thread3/functions/*.log
```

So result will be:

```
./thread1/main/main-22-11-2019.log
./thread1/functions/functions-22-11-2019.log
./thread1/functions/functions-20-11-2019.log
./thread2/main/main-22-11-2019.log
./thread2/functions/functions-20-11-2019.log
```

But now I need to download files (to local macbook - e.g. to desktop) that contain string apple to new folder with specific hierarchy:

```
download
  thread1 
    main-22-11-2019.log
    functions-22-11-2019.log
    functions-20-11-2019.log
  thread2
    main-22-11-2019.log
    functions-20-11-2019.log
```

Any idea?

Comment: `download files` - you mean _copy_ files? You "download" from a remote location, like from a server via http or ftp. You "copy" files into a destination.

Comment: download from remote location

Comment: Use `scp` to copy through the ssh tunnel. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-scp-command-to-securely-transfer-files/